# Bash- populate an associative array using a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, associative-array

So I have this to be entered into and associative array:

```
47 SPRINGGREEN2
48 SPRINGGREEN1
49 MEDIUMSPRINGGREEN
50 CYAN2
51 CYAN1
52 DARKRED
53 DEEPPINK4
```

It's part of a bash script. 
I'm looking for a way to make an associative array out of this, so it would look like

```
    declare -A cols=( [SPRINGGREEN2]="0;47"...[DEEPPINK4]="0;53" )
```

I can do that quite easily manually.

But I want to use a for loop to populate the array cols=( [KEY]="vALUE" )
For loop will take 47, 48, 49...53 and out it into VALUE field, 
and SPRINGGREEN2...DEEPPINK4 into the key field.

I was thinking using awk but couldn't figure our how to isolate the two fields and use each entry to populate the array.

Comment: Use a [`while read`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash/1521498#1521498) loop

Comment: `key=']'; declare -A aarr=( ["$key"]=value )` or `declare -A aarr=( [\]]=value )` gives `bash: []]=value: bad array subscript`

Answer (score 8):

Are you intending to read from the file and populate the `cols` array?

```
declare -a cols
while read num color; do
    cols[$num]=$color
done < file.txt
for key in "${!cols[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${cols[$key]}"; done
```

Oh the other hand, if you already have the associative array and you also want a "reversed" array:

```
declare -a rev_cols
for color in "${!cols[@]}"; do
    rev_cols[${cols[$color]#*;}]=$color
done
for key in "${!rev_cols[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${rev_cols[$key]}"; done
```

Comment: is there a way to populate the array if the set of keys and values are on the same file as the array (bash script in this case) Basically I want to input those keys, values into an array and then use that array for something else. I have about 255 keys, values I need to put into an associative array and I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: More details please. What does the script look like. Please edit your question.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far. What I know is I want to enter 255 lines of Key and Values and enter them into an associative array. What I want to do with that array? It's basically going to be used to print input/strings into random colored characters.

Comment: How about this: create a separate bash script that contains only the variable declaration. When you write a script that wants to use colours, you can `source /path/to/colors.bash`

Comment: It would work, except it's for an assignment, and including a source file would be a hassle.

Comment: the '-a' needs to be '-A'